# Alternative to CasperJS for use with Cucumber.js

Tags: javascript, cucumber, bdd, phantomjs

After lots of research and trial and error I have chosen the following stack for Frontend BDD testing:

- Cucumber.js
- CasperJS (through SpookyJS)
- PhantomJS

I would like to avoid CasperJS run queues and use PhantomJS directly (through [phantom-proxy](https://github.com/sheebz/phantom-proxy)) with callbacks in each step:

```
@World = (cb) ->
    @phantom = require "phantom-proxy"
    cb()

@Before (cb) ->
    self = this
    @phantom.create {}, (proxy) ->
        self.proxy = proxy
        self.page = proxy.page
        cb()

@After (cb) ->
    @proxy.end ->
        cb()

@When /^I go to url "([^"]*)"$/, (url, cb) ->
    @page.open url, ->
        cb()
```

making the whole more logical and BDD-like.

Additionally, SpookyJS doesn't provide a full API for CasperJS.

The PhantomJS API, however, is quite low-level. Is there any other tool that provides CasperJS-like functionality (clicking, waiting for elements, etc) for Node.js without using run queues?

Comment: Ewww... running PhantomJs from within Node is ugly. I speak from many failings with that. Solution: PhantomJs + Casper can be ran as a standalone, and is much easier to configure and customize as such. I can't advise you to run the standalone on the Linux version, however-another failure on my part. BUT the phantom.exe ran from the windows command line is a godsend. It just works. A server can be built in less than 20 lines, as well. CasperJS + your own tests are a breeze to build and customize, too, straight from the examples provided at CasperJs example page. Highly recommended.

Comment: As far as i researched, it worked well for single-page apps, but not for websites, where one needs to navigate from page to page. Finally we went with testing inside django with lettuce and ghostdriver. works like charm actually and is very fast.

Comment: You should use https://github.com/AllegiantAir/cucumber-defaults

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Mocha-PhantomJS](https://github.com/metaskills/mocha-phantomjs) might be just what you're looking for.

Alternatively, [WebdriverJS](http://webdriver.io/) has support for cucumber tests.

If you want to be more low-level you can try interfacing with the [selenium-webdriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs) directly. Here's a [demo](https://github.com/keithamus/WebCumberNode) on github.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/) which has a [cucumber syntax add-on (mocha-cackes)](https://github.com/quangv/mocha-cakes) and/or chai and it's plugins [chai-jquery](https://github.com/chaijs/chai-jquery) and [chai-timers](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-timers).

Also [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/) comes with cucumber syntax support through the plugin [karma-cucumber](https://www.npmjs.org/package/karma-cucumber).

Both Karma and Mocha allow you to run your tests against real devices using launchers for saucelabs or browserstack for example.

Hope it helps.